# C++ run-time template constant

Tags: c++, templates

I was trying to create a user-defined container type with `using` and private members in the class, which are not compile-time constants. The is not valid and complained by the compiler. Those private member constants will only be initialized at runtime. Is there such a remedy for this kind of scenario?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class SudokuBoard
{
private:
    Board _board_data;
    int _BOX_SIZE;
    int _BOARD_SIZE;
    const int _MAX_VALUE = _BOARD_SIZE;
    const int _NUM_CONSTRAINTS = 4;
    
public:
    template <class T, int ROW, int COL>
    using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, COL>, ROW>;
    using CoverMatrix = Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE * _BOARD_SIZE * _MAX_VALUE, _BOARD_SIZE * _BOARD_SIZE * _NUM_CONSTRAINTS>;
    using Board = Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE, _BOARD_SIZE>;

    SudokuBoard(const std::string& filename);

    void set_board_data(int row, int col, int num) { _board_data[row][col] = num; }
    int get_board_data(int row, int col) const { return _board_data[row][col]; }
    Board get_board_data() const { return _board_data; }
    int at(int row, int col) const { return _board_data[row][col]; }
    
    // Prints the Sudoku board
    friend void print_board(const SudokuBoard& board);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const SudokuBoard& board);

    int indexInCoverMatrix(int row, int col, int num);
    int createBoxConstraints(CoverMatrix coverMatrix, int header);
    int createColumnConstraints(CoverMatrix coverMatrix, int header);
    int createRowConstraints(CoverMatrix coverMatrix, int header);
    int createCellConstraints(CoverMatrix coverMatrix, int header);
    void createCoverMatrix(CoverMatrix coverMatrix);
    void convertToCoverMatrix(Board board, CoverMatrix coverMatrix);
};
```

Comment: Template parameters must be known at compile-time. If you have a limited set of parameters, you can specify all the valid options at compile-time and let the user choose which one to use at run-time.

Comment: If the values are known only at run-time, they obviously cannot be used in templates. C++ templates are purely compile-time concept in contract to C#.

Comment: By definition a constant must be initialized at compile time. If it is initialized at run time, it is only a const variable and cannot be used where a true constant (or constexpr) is expected.

Comment: @SergeBallesta not in C++, that is why C++11 introduced `constexpr`

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Your `Board` class is missing

Comment: @MarekR : C++11 has now been around  for more than 10 years... When I see a question tagged C++ with no precision I assume at least C++14 or C++17...

Comment: When the size is only known at runtime, dont use an array whose size must be known at compile time, use a  `std::vector`

Comment: identifiers starting with `_` followed by a capital letter are reserverd (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). You better avoid them, because with some bad luck they migt clash and you'll get weird bugs

Comment: @SergeBallesta You have missed my point, I meant `const` is not same as `constexpr` and `const` can be evaluated at runtime. Simply your statement was not precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue you get, compiling this, with a placeholder `class Board{};` is something like:

> Compilation failed
> For more information see the output window
> x86-64 clang 12.0.1 - 405ms
>
> :23:37: error: invalid use of non-static data member '_BOARD_SIZE'
> using CoverMatrix = Matrix;

What this tells you is that the compiler needs to know at compile them about the sizes and types of your templates.

A first step is to make them static const. That way, the compiler knows at compile time:

```
static const int _BOARD_SIZE = 9;
static const int _MAX_VALUE = _BOARD_SIZE;
```

(constexpr give you other, more modern, options but this is a starting point)

Then, you'll probably want to have your SudokuBoard class itself templated on some type `T`. But I can't get there as you didn't provide the `Board` class.

Comment: Why not `constexpr` ?

Comment: it's more characters :-) and I'm biased into finding simpler the approach I learned first, before C++11.

Comment: concerning last paragraph: `using Board = Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE, _BOARD_SIZE>;`

Comment: @jeffrey ```Board``` is a user-defined type ```Board = Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE, _BOARD_SIZE>;```, not a class.